# Deploy AWS SAM functions using already created roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

When trying to deploy to AWS using AWS SAM CLI my Lambda functions using the following script:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /Users/ndelvalle/Projects/foo/functions/packaged-template.yaml --stack-name foo --region sa-east-1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

I got the following error in the stack events:

```
API: iam:CreateRole User: arn:aws:iam::user/nico is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource
```

This is because I don't have role creation permissions on my account. That is why I wonder if there is a way to define pre-created roles to my lambdas, so the script does not need to create the role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more information needed to answer this for you.  Many different permissions come into play when deploying with SAM. I implemented SAM template for my company to manage our lambda stacks.  We needed to give our Java Developers working on the stacks the same permissions that the SAM template implicitly and explicitly creates, beyond just creating roles. For this we created several special groups in IAM that we attached our Serverless Devs too.  It is possible to assign specific predefined roles to Lambdas, https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction. If you define a role in the template, it does not automatically create a role. However, if you are declaring other resources like Api Gateway and DynamoDB, you will still run into problems.

So long story short, if you are working with SAM its better you have your Sys admin give you permissions to Create role, and you will need other permissions as well, or have the deployment of the SAM template done by a Job runner like Jenkins (that has the permissions).  It it is too permissive for your team/company, maybe SAM is not a good solution... Best to switch to something like pure CloudFormation and abandon a developer oriented workflow.  Somethings to think about, hope its helpful.

Comment: TBH it's pretty scary that the SAM doc itself encourages you to run under admin account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ***Role*** property as mentioned [in the docs](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction) for AWS::Serverless::Function

A sample template which creates a new lambda without creating a new role,

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Tracing: Active
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: True

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Role: <ARN of ROLE>
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints: 
        - app.ts

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```